# Syntax error when including query in code

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I think I've got a syntax error with my query I cant find the error. I get the error at the  "1/1/1990". Anyone know hat i'm doing wrong here?

```
  Set rsCanCounter = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblActionLog Where groupNum = '" & txtGroupNr.Value & "' And DateClosed < '" & 1/1/1900, dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting in the question shows mis-matched quotes.  Pay close attention to your single-quotes and double-quotes.  This query is never even going to reach the database because the code won't compile like this.

Comment: Sorry! I was trying to fix it the way David suggested. The quotes are confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a string variable to hold your `SELECT` statement.  After you overcome the quoting issues so you can create a valid string in VBA, then use that variable with `OpenRecordset`.

For example, if the datatypes of your *groupNum* and *DateClosed* fields are both text ...

```vb
Dim strSelect As String
strSelect = "Select * from tblActionLog Where groupNum ='" & _
    Me.txtGroupNr.Value & "' And DateClosed < '1/1/1900'"
Debug.Print strSelect '<-- Ctrl+g to go to Immediate window and see the statement text
Set rsCanCounter = db.OpenRecordset(strSelect, dbOpenDynaset)
```

If *DateClosed* is Date/Time datatype, use `#` instead of quotes to delimit the date value:

```vb
strSelect = "Select * from tblActionLog Where groupNum ='" & _
    Me.txtGroupNr.Value & "' And DateClosed < #1900-1-1#"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

"Select * from tblActionLog Where groupNum ='" & Me.txtGroupNr.Value & "' And DateClosed < #'1-1-1900# And DateClosed is not Null"

I had to add the null exception. is this correct. Am I doing the quotations wrong again

Comment: What?  *DateClosed* can not be both < 1/1/1900 and Null at the same time.  Those conditions contradict each other.  That `WHERE` clause should not return any rows.

Comment: Sorry I fix it. Actually the comment got added before I was finished with it : /

Comment: Aha! :-)  Well, with the condition `DateClosed < #'1-1-1900#`, that makes `DateClosed is not Null` superfluous.  To see if the latest version of the statement is correct, run your code, go to the Immediate window (Ctrl+g), copy the statement text, open a new query in the query designer, switch it to SQL View, paste in the statement text.  Does it work when you then try to run it from the query designer?